# Ansible - SSH Error: data could not be sent to remote host

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ansible

I am trying to use `Ansible 2.7.7` to manage `Ubuntu 16.04 cloud image` but when I try to make connection I get error:

```
SSH Error: data could not be sent to remote host "192.168.111.11". Make sure this host can be reached over ssh
```

If I issue command `ssh ubuntu@192.168.111.11` on the Ansible host I can connect to target server without problems. I can also `sudo` there without password prompt.

If look at logs of the target machine I see that Ansible successfully logged in to the machine:

```
Feb 20 11:44:51 ubuntu sshd[2870]: Accepted publickey for ubuntu from 192.168.111.111 port 56236 ssh2: RSA SHA256:yI...
Feb 20 11:44:51 ubuntu sshd[2870]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
Feb 20 11:44:51 ubuntu systemd-logind[1090]: New session 13 of user ubuntu.
Feb 20 11:44:51 ubuntu sudo:   ubuntu : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/ubuntu ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/sh -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS-kldfjkldjhjljkl; /usr/bin/python
Feb 20 11:44:51 ubuntu sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 20 11:44:51 ubuntu sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Verbose output:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory default.yaml -vvv
ansible-playbook 2.7.7
  config file = /home/admin/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/admin/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/admin/ansible/ansible-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /home/admin/ansible/ansible-env/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
Using /home/admin/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
/home/admin/ansible/inventory did not meet host_list requirements, check plugin documentation if this is unexpected
/home/admin/ansible/inventory did not meet script requirements, check plugin documentation if this is unexpected
Parsed /home/admin/ansible/inventory inventory source with ini plugin

PLAYBOOK: default.yaml *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
1 plays in default.yaml

PLAY [default] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/admin/ansible/default.yaml:3
Using module file /home/admin/ansible/ansible-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/system/setup.py
<192.168.111.11> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ubuntu
<192.168.111.11> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ubuntu -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/admin/.ansible/cp/a9e60c69b0 192.168.111.11 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-tenlfcstwmojszikegdyatixrzpwqwah; /usr/bin/python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
Escalation succeeded
fatal: [192.168.111.11]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "unreachable": true
}

MSG:

SSH Error: data could not be sent to remote host "192.168.111.11". Make sure this host can be reached over ssh
```

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Try with pipelining disabled or without `become`. If that's the case inspect `sudo` and terminal configuration on the remote system.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Thanks, disabling `pipelining` solved the problem.

Comment: It helped you to narrow the number of possible reasons, but in no way solved the real problem...

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Wrong, it solved the problem completely.

Comment: Run the actual ssh command yourself, which appears after `SSH: EXEC ` to see the results. This will give you the error that may not be otherwise visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out my target system required `tty` when using `sudo`.

I was able to make connection my commenting out this line from `ansible.cfg`:

```
pipelining = True
```

Other option would have been disabling setting `requiretty` from sudoer file.

Comment: Remember that this is a workaround. You still have a lingering problem that remains unsolved and will probably come back to bite you in some unexpected way in the future.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate more on @Michael Hampton comment and. Ansible is masking the ssh error.

In my case the true error, shown with verbose level of **-vvvv** was: `Host key verification failed.` and I found the solution here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416166/cant-establish-ssh-connection-debug1-read-passphrase-cant-open-dev-tty-n#answer-416186

Basically, provide the ssh option: `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`

Answer (score 0):

Adding these lines in ansible.cfg fixed this issue for me. [source_link][1]

```
[ssh_connection]
scp_if_ssh = smart
transfer_method = smart
```